# Regular Expression '[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*' doesn't get matched

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to process some sentences in the document of PostgreSQL and do some analysis. In the word spliting stage, I tried to use the regex **'[\w-]+(.[\w-]+)*'** proposed by Lotufo et al. in the article *Modelling the Hurried bug report reading process to summarize
bug reports*. It's quite strange that I cann't get the expected answer using this regex in Python.

```py
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>>> import re
>>> result = re.findall(r'[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*', 'Specifies the directory to use for data storage.')
>>> print(result)
```

I expected to get a list of words：

```
['Specifies', 'the', 'directory', 'to', 'use', 'for', 'data', 'storage']
```

But I only got a list of empty string:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Does any one have any idea what is wrong with my code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use string.split(' ') to segment the sentence, it's easy to understand and improve runtime efficiency.

Comment: This regex has special meaning in spliting the computer words. The function string.split(' ') may work well on the above sentence but for certain sentences it cannot reach the aim of spliting.

Comment: @Chanlen, could you please post a better explanation of what are you trying to accomplish with that regex? More examples of right and wrong input/outputs would be great.

Comment: Sorry for making it confused. I have re-edited the post and it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This works the way you were expecting:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 16 2019, 19:49:22) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181215 (Red Hat 8.2.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> split = re.compile('(\w+)')
>>> split.findall('Specifies the directory to use for data storage.')
['Specifies', 'the', 'directory', 'to', 'use', 'for', 'data', 'storage']
>>>
```

Those square brackets on your regular expression don't feel right. I guess they are the cause.

Comment: This regex is not equivalent to the original one. The regex is supposed to allow dots (except at the beginning and at the end of a word)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Aloso, but yours will allow a string like ```one.two``` being matched as a one single word. Is that the right thing?

Comment: Apparently it is. Just look at the regex `[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*`. We don't know what @Chanlen needs it for, so let's not jump to any conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

The expected strings are matched, but they aren't in a **capturing group**. Use this regex instead:

```py
r'([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)'
```

Note that I added `?:` to the inner parentheses to make them non-capturing.